# How many Critical Hits for Assassinate?

Tags: dnd-5e, surprise

I am currently Playing a Monk 8/ Rogue 4 The Rogue is an Assassin. pg97 of the PHB says that for assassinate the move

> In addition, any hit you score against a creature that is surprised is a critical hit

I attacked a surprise creature with my flurry of blows from the Monk giving me 4 hits. Since the passage on Surprise in chapter 9 doesnt specify how many attacks count for "surprised" my DM ruled that only the first hit was a critical. My argument was that Assassinate uses the word "all" for the hits.

So who is correct via RAW?

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62920/15469), maybe even a duplicate.

Comment: Ahhh yes, yes it is... thanks for the link. I didnt think to search this according to the surprise function.

Answer (score 3):

Your DM is wrong (except that, as DM, they can't be).

A creature is surprised until the end of *its* first turn. If you beat its initiative, then every attack you successfully make is a critical hit.  If you lose initiative, then it isn't surprised on your turn and you lose that benefit of surprise.